# How can I responsive my flutter app with MediaQuery?

Tags: flutter

How can I responsive my flutter app with MediaQuery?

This is all my code:
Please tell me if you know another way to do this
lines **3** and **4** are wrong.
What can I do?

```
    return MaterialApp(
    var wi = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var he = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            width: wi,
            height: he,
            color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 30,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 20,
                  ),
                  width: wi,
                  height: he * 0.3,
                  child: Text(
                    "3,670",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 70,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    );
```

Comment: you should put line 3 and 4 between build and return, not inside a widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in flutter there is many way to make a responsive ui either you use MediaQuery or Expanded or any sort of responsive widget it depend on your app and what you want to achieve or satisfies you, here is the [flutter document for making responsive app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive) if you want to know more widget to make a responsive app.
you should use the `MediaQuery.of(context)` between the `builder` and the `return widget` because `MediaQuery` get the context from the builder
`Note` you can't get the MediaQuery before making the MaterialApp widget, to solve that you should first make the MaterialApp widget then navigate to the another widget
this code is for that

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var wi = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var he = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: wi,
        height: he,
        color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 30,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 20,
              ),
              width: wi,
              height: he * 0.3,
              child: Text(
                "3,670",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 70,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you really need to take some course from [youtube click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ukSR1GRtMU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ) if you want to [read document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro)

Comment: Tnx but I do not know how to use. Can you edit this code for me?